# How to understand the dimensions of the result array after using model.predict()

Tags: python, keras, predict, resnet

I'm recurrencing a code to retrieve the item, but when I debug in model.predict function, I find that the input of this function is with the dimension(1, 224, 224, 3), but the output is (1, 7, 7, 2048). Shouldn't the result of model.predict() be a 1D array which give the probability that the object belongs to each category instead of 4D? How to understand the dimension of this result array?

```
    model_features = model.predict(x, batch_size=1)
```

The concrete code is following:
(This is only part of the whole code and may not run directly)

```
import keras.applications.resnet50
import numpy as np
import os
import pickle
import time
import vse
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model, load_model

model = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(include_top=False)
model_extension == "resnet"

def extract_features_cnn(img_path):
    """Returns a normalized features vector for image path and model specified in parameters file """
    print('Using model', model_extension)
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    if model_extension == "vgg19":
        x = keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input(x)
    elif model_extension == "vgg16":
        x = keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x)
    elif model_extension == "resnet":
        x = keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(x)
    else:
        print('Wrong model name')
    model_features = model.predict(x, batch_size=1)
    x = model_features[0]
    total_sum = sum(model_features[0])
    features_norm = np.array([val / total_sum for val in model_features[0]], dtype=np.float32)
    if model_extension == "resnet":
        print("reshaping resnet")
        features_norm = features_norm.reshape(2048, -1)
    return features_norm
```

Comment: You have set `include_top=False` which means removing dense layers from pre-trained model. If you want dense layers, set `include_top=True`. Then you will get what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough but I will try to explain as much as I can understand your question. Your model only has ResNet which has the only convolutional layers and it does not have a linear layer which can cause a result that represents the probability of classes. Your result is not 4D as you think. In your output shape which is `(1, 7, 7, 2048)`, 1 represents batch size. It means you gave only 1 image to the network and get 1 result. 7s represents your output size which is 7x7. And 2048 represents your output channels. If you want to have the probability of classes you need to add a linear layer at the end of the ResNet network. You can add it with the argument `include_top=True` and you can specify class number with argument `classes=1000`.

[Here](https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/) is the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However when I try to do this I just get this error: 
URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/resnet/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5: None -- [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution ( I am a beginner in this field, how can i fix that? )

Comment: Do you have an internet connection on your kernel?